# rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView can't play video from res

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Hi I used a library called [rtoshiro/FullscreeVideoView](https://github.com/rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView) for play a video.
But when I used a link of URL , it's pretty good . But when I parse my res file path its seen an error.

**E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)**

**XML:**

```
 <com.github.rtoshiro.view.video.FullscreenVideoLayout
            android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            />
```

**JAVA:**

```
    FullscreenVideoLayout videoLayout==findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
            videoLayout.setActivity(this);
            try {
    String path="android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test;
                videoLayout.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    //          videoLayout.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));

   //  Here , when I used webside link , it's playing good but otherwise not wroking.

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            videoLayout.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                }
            });
```

Error:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jx4G.png)

or See this logcat:
when I pressed on playbutton it's showing...

```
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 0
D/FullscreenVideoView: start
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: start
V/MediaPlayer: start
E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0
V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
V/MediaPlayer: callback application
V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
D/FullscreenVideoLayout: startCounter
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
D/FullscreenVideoView: onError called - -38 - 0
D/FullscreenVideoLayout: stopCounter
D/FullscreenVideoLayout: onCompletion
D/FullscreenVideoLayout: stopCounter
```

Comment: What was the error?post here.

Comment: Please see this post again, I updated now.

Comment: Not an image, paste a specific portion of your `logcat` which you think is the reason for your problem.

Comment: Please will you come to my laptop via team viewer?

Comment: @meditat bro, see this post again. I attached my logcat error.

Comment: probably You are getting this error because you are calling `mediaPlayer.start()` before it has reached the prepared state.

Comment: No, I am already try that also.